# Can you access defined cascaded styles individually that are associated with an html tag?

Tags: css

Problem stems from a defined CSS template similar to the following:

```
.style1 .style2 form,
.style1FIX .style2 form {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.style1 .style2 form label,
.style1FIX .style2 form label {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.style1 .style2 form select,
.style1FIX .style2 form select {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}
```

The nested elements fall into the form tag and associating label/select tags as well.

Basically, I'm transfering the designs into .aspx pages and the issue is stemming from the fact that my pages use "global" form references (i.e. encase entire page) as I have embeded controls around the form area content.

So when I added in the tags (similar to below)

```
<form> 
<div class="style1FIX ">
    <div class="style2">
        <div class="other">
        </div>
        <div class="other2">
            <div class="style2">
                <!-- START original defined "form" tag position --> 
                <div class="other3">
                    <label>SGDS</label>
                    <input type="text" name=""/><span>*</span>
                </div>
                <div class="other3">
                    <label style="margin-top:15px; width: 90%">earhyhta</label>
                    <select name="" style="width: 98%">
                        <option>--Select--</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <!-- END original defined "form" tag position --> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

the form elements are totally not following the defined style. So the gist of the question is how can I reference the element styles I need without having to create a new set of CSS class elements to get the desired formatting. I tried

```
<div class="style1 style2 form"></div>
```

but didn't work as I'm not too sure if you can directly reference a style assigned to a tag element.

Any and all help apprecited.

Dave

**UPDATE**

After thinking on, the simplest solution in this case, since delaing with "form" tags which are very targeted in use, I simply replaced the tag reference "form" with a class definition ".form" in the css and replaced all `"<form>"` tags with `<div class="form">...` in the html content

Again, I'm lucky in this case with the issue being styling under a form tag but it would be nice to know if there are any ways to reference nested styles individually outside of their nested tags.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing your css from `.style1 .style2 form label` to `.style1 .style2 label` for all of your different references.

You may still have to modify your page a little more than that but that should be a good start.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Issue is that this is an inherited design and I can't just add additional style items without the possibility of affecting other page styles (i.e. labels may exist outside of forms on different pages nested within .style1 .style2 and those labels may have a defined or a different style). I'm looking to see if I can reference the existing style for the items without the defined "form" tag